# camel-opentracing: adding baggage to span as cross-cutting-concern

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, mdc, opentracing

I have a camel blueprint application with many routes, all called from a process manager.

The process manager sends a process instance id.

I want to use the incoming process instance id in opentracing spans and in MDC logging.

The obvious idea is an interceptor at the beginning of all routes which puts the id into a tracer baggage. But for that I must change all routes manually.

The camel-opentracing component instruments the routes behind the scenes, so that tracing becomes a cross-cutting concern. Is there a way to customize the tracing so that it adds data to all traces?

The application runs in an OSGi container, no Spring Boot.

Comment: Yeah maybe we can add some api to make it easier to hook in a custom enricher where you can add custom data. We did some improvements for camel-opentracing recently, that makes this partly easier, but there is likely need for something more. You are welcome to create a JIRA then we wont forget and can take a look at this. You are welcome to help with this.

Comment: @ClausIbsen see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-14322

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean: decorators. https://github.com/apache/camel/commit/6b089f89c84acc81b0e918cd838f1b2619d75fa4